# Group by time interval and get first row satisfying condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
,columnname
2014-01-02 09:30:00-05:00,5
2014-01-02 09:31:00-05:00,6
2014-01-02 09:32:00-05:00,5
2014-01-02 09:33:00-05:00,71
2014-01-02 09:34:00-05:00,98

2014-01-02 09:35:00-05:00,1
2014-01-02 09:36:00-05:00,91
2014-01-02 09:37:00-05:00,9
2014-01-02 09:38:00-05:00,1
2014-01-02 09:39:00-05:00,9

2014-01-02 09:40:00-05:00,1
2014-01-02 09:41:00-05:00,9
2014-01-02 09:42:00-05:00,1
2014-01-02 09:43:00-05:00,84
2014-01-02 09:44:00-05:00,1

2014-01-02 09:45:00-05:00,3
2014-01-02 09:46:00-05:00,1
2014-01-02 09:47:00-05:00,9
2014-01-02 09:48:00-05:00,2
2014-01-02 09:49:00-05:00,5
```

I need to find, for each 5 minutes interval, the first row having > 10.
So the result would be:

```
,columnname
2014-01-02 09:30:00-05:00,71
2014-01-02 09:35:00-05:00,91
2014-01-02 09:40:00-05:00,84
2014-01-02 09:45:00-05:00,NaN
```

How can I get it?

Comment: you mean : `df[df['columnname'].gt(10)].resample('5min').first()` ?

Comment: That works. You should add that as an answer.

Comment: Your expected output is wrong, 84 is in the hour range of 10

Comment: @Erfan thanks. I have just correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first filter columns which are greater than 10 , then use [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) and `first`

```
df[df['columnname'].gt(10)].resample('5min').first()
```

EDIT:

```
df['columnname'].where(df['columnname'].gt(10)).resample('5min').first()
```

---

```
2014-01-02 09:30:00-05:00    71.0
2014-01-02 09:35:00-05:00    91.0
2014-01-02 09:40:00-05:00    84.0
2014-01-02 09:45:00-05:00     NaN
Freq: 5T, Name: columnname, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Actually the last row (2014-01-02 09:45:00-05:00,NaN) is not showing

Comment: @Alfonso_MA Check the EDIT

Answer (score 1):

Using `DataFrame.query`, `DataFrame.GroupBy` and`pd.Grouper`:

```
df.query('columnname>10').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5min')).first()

                           columnname
index                                
2014-01-02 09:30:00-05:00          71
2014-01-02 09:35:00-05:00          91
2014-01-02 09:40:00-05:00          84
```